# Atomic compare and exchange implementation

Tags: c++, gcc, locking, atomic, inline-assembly

I have the following code snippet for compare and exchange

```
 18     static size_t compareAndExchange( volatile size_t* addr, size_t oldval, size_t newval )
 19     {
 20       size_t ret;
 21       __asm__ volatile( "lock cmpxchgq %2, %1\n\t"
 22                     :"=a"(ret), "+m"(*addr)
 23                     : "r"(newval), "0"(oldval)
 24                     : "memory" );
 25       return ret;
 26     }
```

Below is the test for the compare and exchange

```
  4 struct node
  5 {
  6     struct node* next;
  7     int locked;
  8
  9     node():next( 0 ), locked( false ) {}
 10 };
 11
 12 int main()
 13 {
 14     struct node* head = 0;
 15     struct node* temp = new struct node;
 16
 17     struct node* ret = reinterpret_cast< struct node* > (
 18                           AtomicUtils::compareAndExchange(
 19                             reinterpret_cast< volatile size_t*>( &head ),
 20                             0,
 21                             reinterpret_cast< size_t >( temp )
 22                           )
 23                        ) ;
 24
 25     std::cout<< "\nExpected: Ret = " << 0 << "Found: " << 0 << std::endl;
 26     std::cout<< "\nExpected: head = " << temp << "Found: " << head << std::endl;
 27 }
```

Questions:

1) Currently to set the value of head atomically, I'm cheating by converting the size_t** to size_t* pointer by a reinterpret_cast. This looks ugly. Is there a better way (by maybe a better implementation of inline assembly) to achieve the same effect?

2) Why do we need volatile qualifier for the argument?

Comment: Can you use `std::atomic` from C++11 ?

Comment: In my company we don't have a gcc version which supports c++11

Comment: Does that code even work? It looks like you're never setting the accumulator...

Comment: @KerrekSB: cmpxcgh gives "result" in EAX.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: It also expects the "input" in EAX...

Comment: Ah, yes, but '%0' is the same as '=a' in the beginning of the asm statement, which means that `old` gets loaded into EAX (or RAX in this case).

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Ah, right - that makes sense.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Hm, I like the C++11 design better of updating `oldval` in-place and returning a `bool`. It doesn't throw away information that you already have, and saves you a redundant comparison later...

Comment: Of course, that's another possible solution.

Comment: May I know why the question is down voted ?

Comment: I didn't downvote the question, but if I did it would be because using inline asm is typically a [bad idea](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm).  I normally recommend using builtins such as [__sync_val_compare_and_swap](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html) or the atomics.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, you could use templates:

```
template<typename T>
static T compareAndExchange( volatile T* addr, T oldval, T newval )
{
  .... rest of code should remain the same ... 
}
```

And your test-code would now be:

```
 node* ret = AtomicUtils::compareAndExchange(&head, 0, temp);
```

(I take it you know about std::atomic and it's members, and you are just doing this as a learning exercise [apparently other reasons for not using this, I see])

gcc also supprt builtin atomics (that is, functions that the compiler can directly translate to machine code), one of which is `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap`.

See more here: 
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html

Edit: 
You would notice if it goes wrong if you change this:

```
 std::cout<< "\nExpected: Ret = " << 0 << "Found: " << 0 << std::endl;
```

to:

```
 std::cout<< "\nExpected: Ret = " << 0 << "Found: " << ret << std::endl;
```

Edit2: As to your second question, about `volatile`: You don't need it for your swap function as such [other than on the `__asm__` itself, since that prevents the compiler from optimising it and potentially changing the order of instructions, etc]. You do need it if you are ever going to use a `volatile T*` argument to the swap function itself, or you'll need to `const_cast` away the `volatile` attribute.

Comment: I'm using clang. So, can't use the gcc atomics.

Comment: @KodeWarrior: I was pretty sure that clang++ is g++ compatible in this context, but if you have a reasonably new clang, you should be able to use http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#langext-c11-atomic

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Appreciate it ! I'm currently trying to play around with inline assembly as a learning exercise.

Comment: I understand that. It's just that it is much less portable (for example, if you compile with -m32, your code won't work. Builtins take care of that (as well as supporting arbitrary pointer types, for example).

Comment: yes, what you say definitely makes sense. Thank you.